# Scan which DB System is running in Domain?

Tags: sql, database

I was wondering if it's possible to detect which database system a server is running if all you know is IP/Port ?

Basically I'm running .NET Code on a machine in the AD domain, as a user with near admin privileges and I'm trying to find out if a server (which is in the same domain) that I specify by IP Adress or hostname (optional: Port is included) is running a sql database on that device and if so which type (SQL Server, Oracle Database, MySQL...).

I tried using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection but the problem is that I don't have the Database-/Instance-name or the login-data at that point so I can't create the connection.

I was considering trying to read the Registry remotely but during my research I read that the registry information changes frequently with updates which makes it only a short-term solution. Also I wouldn't know how to access the registry remotely.

Maybe by reading the process list? Or is there a simpler solution for this?

I know it's rather easy for SQL Server (Microsoft) because of the SQL Server Browser, so you can simply use `[System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources()` in Powershell, which is basically everything that I'm looking for but it only works when the service is started and only for the Microsoft server, not for MySQL or OracleDB.

Comment: What means `near admin privileges`? Run RDP and check interactively.

Comment: Well, the user will have as many privileges as will be needed. Checking interactively won't work because this will have to work for large domains with possibly hundreds or thousands of devices.
Basically I am looking for `[System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources()` for Oracle and MySQL

Comment: Hint for [Oracle here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2185980/2224701).

Comment: I am not saying that I am an admin of a huge network. I am developing a plugin for another program that needs to know where there's instances of one of those 3 database systems. Sure, I could just have the user type in all of them manually but the whole point of the thing is that you don't forget any.